# Where we are giving password by using BCP command?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, bcp

I am pretty much new to bcp but I researched quite a bit and can not find any resource that says where we are actually sending the user name and password to the database with this command. So everyone can access the database?

```
bcp AdventureWorks2008.HumanResources.Employee out C:\Data\EmployeeData.dat -T
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
bcp AdventureWorks2008.HumanResources.Employee out C:\Data\EmployeeData.dat -T -c -U<login_id> -P<password> -S<server_name\instance_name>
```

Comment: So the login_id should be between <> or [] ?

Comment: no, you dont have to enclose username or pswd in brackets, here is the example: bcp AdventureWorks2008.HumanResources.Employee out C:\Data\EmployeeData.dat -S localhost\SqlSrv2008 –Uuser1 –Ppassword123

Comment: I had to remove the -T option (trusted connection) from the answer to use sql server authentication user and password

Answer (score 7):

You aren't sending the username and password with the -T argument. In fact, it won't send any specified username and password to SQL Server if -T is present in the command line.

-T tells BCP to use Windows Authentication to connect to SQL Server. It will operate as the user who's running the command.

Answer (score 4):

`[-U login_id] [-P password]`

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174646(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: So the login_id should be between <> or [] ?

Answer (score 1):

sample query with db credentials

```
bcp "SELECT * from yourtable" queryout c:\StockItemTransactionID_c.txt -c -Uusername -Pdbpassword -Sinstance -dYourDBName
```

Answer (score -1):

Removing -T has worked for me.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question, it may work but it doesnt answer the question